# Automatically pin Docker dependencies

Tags: docker

`Dockerfile`s usually contain `FROM` lines referring to a *moving* third-party image, such as "ubuntu:23.10" or even just "ubuntu". I'd like to pin all such references to the current digest of that image, so that it doesn't keep changing. That is, I'm looking for a tool which can change a `Dockerfile` line like

```
FROM ubuntu:23.10
```

to

```
FROM ubuntu:23.10@sha256:13f233a16be210b57907b98b0d927ceff7571df390701e14fe1f3901b2c4a4d7
```

Bonuses:

- The tool should ideally be able to handle [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage), where some `FROM` lines refer back to previous stages of the same `Dockerfile`.
- Docker Compose support would be nice.
- The tool should actually parse the `Dockerfile` (rather than using naive regexes), so that it doesn't trip over any unusual syntax variations, like having space characters at the start of a `FROM` line or even multi-line `FROM` commands.

Manual workaround:

1. Print the `FROM` values:

   ```
   grep --only-matching --perl-regexp '(?<=FROM ).*' Dockerfile
   ```

   In case of a multi-stage build you need to manually exclude references to previous stages from the rest of the steps.
2. [Get the current digest suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32046334/96588) per `IMAGE`:

   ```
   docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' IMAGE | grep --only-matching '@.*'
   ```

   - If Docker complains about "Error: No such object: IMAGE", run `docker pull IMAGE` and retry.

     - If Docker complains about "Error response from daemon: manifest for IMAGE:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown", you'll have to manually find the relevant tag in [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) and pull that instead.
3. Add the output from the previous step to the `FROM` line.

Comment: What's the problem of scripting the manual workaround? You could also make the regex work with multistage builds.

Comment: Not a problem per se, I just wanted to check whether there's an existing tool. I might not have the time to create it myself (it's for work).